# How to uninstall programs (Comodo)

Tags: uninstall

So Comodo wont work properly so I want to uninstall it. I dont want to install other programs that are not legitiment

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Gdebi was used to install the .deb file

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Open the terminalCtrl + Alt + T
2. Enter this: `sudo apt-get remove comodo`
3. If you get an error "Package not found" or something similar try this: `sudo apt-get remove comodo*` or `sudo apt-get remove comodo:i386`
4. Press y, and then enter

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove EVERYTHING that the program has installed (except for perhaps what it has done with your direction) run "sudo apt-get purge " to completely remove it and any unnecessary dependencies that it installed during its own installation